# Why does this Angular app have errors when running npm start?

Tags: angular, npm

I am getting errors while running `npm start`:

[image]

I have run another app, which is working fine. This problem came up after I formatted my laptop.

I've also tried `npm install` command but no use.

Comment: Have you ran the apps after formatting your laptop or before?

Make sure you have node.js and npm. Did you follow the instructions on how to install the app?

Comment: i have installed node.js. other apps are are working fine except this app

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you did not install `gulp`. Install it globally as well.

Comment: i just install gulp npm install --save-dev gulp
but same problem

Answer (score 0):

Install gulp globally:
npm install --global gulp